# Symmetricity in Kaiming initialization

Tags: probability-distributions, machine-learning

Kaiming initialization paper says that "If we let $w_{l-1}$ have a symmetric distribution around zero and $b_{l-1 } = 0$, then $y_{l-1}$ has zero mean and has a symmetric distribution around zero". Can someone explain how symmetricity of $w_{l-1}$ leads to symmetricity of $y_{l-1}$ ? A mathematical proof would be great.

Comment: What do all your variables mean?

Comment: @EricWofsey $w_{l-1} $ are the weights in the previous layer of the neural net. $b_{l-1}$ the bias and $y_{l-1}$ the weighted input of the previous layer. Here is the link of the paper [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf)